# 'Undefined reference to function' issue even after linking the library which has the defination

Tags: c, gcc, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I am trying to create an executable with .o ,.so, .a files.

Here is my build command:-

```
pkgs/gcc/v4.8.3/bin/gcc -L/usr/X11R6/lib -O2 -DUSE_FLEX -Wall -Wno-char-subscripts -fPIC -DLINUX -DG_DISABLE_CONST_RETURNS -fno-strict-aliasing -o ../build/kl/Release/test/bin/pure.exe -L../build/kl/Release/test/modules ../build/kl/Release/test/maker/constrfunc.TCL.o ../../build/kl/Release/test/maker/pvdbprocs.TCL.o .. ../build/kl/Release/test/maker/maker/memmaker.TCL.o .. ../build/kl/Release/test/maker/modules/libdenbase.a .. ../build/kl/Release/test/maker/guibase.o -litk3.2 -litcl4.0.0 -ltk8.3 -lcdnviptcl8.4 -litclstub4.0.0 -ldenbase -lglib-2.0 -ldenbase -lX11 -ldl -lm -lviputil -lvippli -lcdsCommonMT_sh -lpthread  -L/home/dlb/extlibs/arm/lib
```

I have libraries which have definitions of the functions at path "-L/home/dlb/extlibs/arm/lib" . Still it is throwing error below.

Error:

```
../build/kl/Release/test/maker/guibase.o: In function `decodeAddrList':
tree234.c:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `ptritclStubsPtr'
tree234.c:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `ptrlitclStubsPtr'
tree234.c:(.text+0x12c): undefined reference to `ptrlitclStubsPtr'
tree234.c:(.text+0x140): undefined reference to `ptrlitclStubsPtr'
```

I have the symbol in library which is at path /home/dlb/extlibs/arm/lib  :-

**Command:-**

```
readelf -s libitcl4.0.0.so | grep ptrlitclStubsPtr

348: 0000000000060f10     8 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   24 ptrlitclStubsPtr
```

Am I missing some thing here?

Note, OP has provided more info in a repost of the same question;
quote from comment by OP:
"Due to some privacy issues...I am renaming the symbols.. It was edited by me... It was typo...I just corrected it...:)"
I.e. the identifiers in the error message and the grep line and the output of the grep line have been manually altered.

Comment: I think the `-L...` need to go before the `-l...` switches for libtcl *et al*.

Comment: it will be better to a write a Makefile ,if your build command is this much big.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya, actuall symbol name is 'ptrlitclStubsPtr' .. I just edited the question.. please check.

Comment: @zappy, the command is from build log only. I am not running separately. it is from makefile.

Comment: @PaulR, I tried that, but it didn't worked :(

Comment: Then better to post your make file also

Comment: Are you sure both the library and the tree234.o have been compiled for the same target(32bit/64bit)?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya, that I didn't checked.. How can I do that.. Can you please share the command?

Comment: Yes, it seems like both are compiled on 64 bit.                                                                                      [lpssc@klot02 maker]$ file tree234.o
/lan/workspace/kumarpet/lpddr5_arm/lpddr5_branch/src/main/cvip/build/Linux-64bit/Release/lib/tree234.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped                                                                                                     objdump -f libitcl4.0.0.so                                                                                            architecture: aarch64, flags 0x0000

Comment: Now the next question, is there any other libitcl4.0.0.so in any of the `-L...` path? Try to manually link __this__ so by providing it's full path instead of the `-litcl.4.0.0`.

Comment: I just verified that there is no 'libtcl4.0.0' library in any of the paths except '/home/dlb/extlibs/arm/lib' . I have also tried giving full path to library '/home/dlb/extlibs/arm/lib/libtcl4.0.0.so' .. Still it did't woks :(

Comment: @SteveSummit, Actually guibase.o is getting from outside. which is not compiled in our build. Usually,  If the symbol is shown as LOCAL it wont work ?

Comment: @jerry Yes.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the functions you're asking about are *local* to the file where they were defined.  That is, it looks like they were explicitly intended not (and not even allowed) to be called externally.

That is, somewhere within the source for the shared library `libitcl4.0.0.so` probably appears a declaration like:

```
static tclStubs *ptrlitclStubsPtr;
```

That keyword `static` indicates that the *visibility* of the resulting symbol `ptrlitclStubsPtr` is confined to its own source file.

I infer all of this from the fact that your reported `readelf` output includes the line

```
348: 0000000000060f10     8 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   24 ptrlitclStubsPtr
```

That flag `LOCAL` indicates that the symbol is local.  If it were global, intended (and able) to be called externally, the flag `GLOBAL` would appear instead.

Why are variables made private (`static`) like this, so you can't use them?  It's a software engineering thing, "information hiding", intended to reduce the "width" of the interface between you and a library like `libitcl4`.  Symbols that are private are more intimately tied to the implementation decisions within `libitcl4`, decisions which are *not* supposed to be visible to, or any concern of, the callers.  It's thought that, if callers were to have access to those symbols, callers would also have to know other implementation details, meaning that the author of `libitcl4` would then be unable to change those implementation details without breaking (invalidating) the calling code.  So to prevent that situation,  the choice is usually made to make it impossible for the caller to become dependent in this way.

In this situation you basically have three paths forward:

1. Remove the `static` tags from the variable declarations in the sources to `libitcl4.0.0.so`.  (This obviously requires that you have access to the sources to `libitcl4.0.0.so`, and the ability to rebuild it.  It's also probably a very bad idea.  As I've explained, those symbols were probably made static for a good reason.)
2. Add a new function within `libitcl4.0.0.so` which does whatever you need done, and which, by virtue of its placement within the same source file, does have access to those symbols.  (This, too, requires that you have access to and the ability to rebuild ``libitcl4.0.0.so`.)
3. Find some other way of doing whatever you need done, using the existing public facilities of `libitcl4.0.0.so`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Unfortunately , we don't have source for that library.. But,i found one alternate library 'libcdnviptcl8.4' which has this symbols 'GLOBAL '                                                                              readelf -s libcdnviptcl8.4.so | grep prttclStubsPtr
   636: 00000000000d8068     8 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   24 ptrtclStubsPtr         I have executed the command including that library and still facing the same issue.